# What is the minimum round robin scheduing interval supported by Linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduling

For some reason, I want to have 10 processes share the same CPU core by affinity.

As you know, to achieve CPU sharing between processes, we can exploit the Linux round robin (RR) scheduling policy.

For Linux kernel 3.9 and later, the RR scheduling interval can be set by changing the file `/proc/sys/kernle/sched_rr_timeslice_ms`. The default RR scheduling interval is 100ms.

My questions are:

1. I want the RR scheduling interval to be 100µs, i.e., one process is executed for a period of 100µs, then another process is executed. But I failed to set the `/proc/sys/kernle/sched_rr_timeslice_ms` with a value of less than 1ms. I wonder if the minimum RR scheduling interval supported by current Linux kernel is 1ms.
2. Is anybody know what minimum RR scheduling interval is supported by Windriver Linux? As Windriver Linux is widely used for embedded system which requires good OS real-time performance.
3. I wonder if I can have all the 10 processes to be executed at least once within 1ms by using mutex. That is, one process executes for 100µs, then unlock the mutex so that another process can lock and execute. Does this mechanism work?
4. If the above mentioned method doesn't work, what if the 10 processes are changed to 10 threads. Is there any high efficiency thread switch mechanism avaliable?

Comment: I don't think there's a difference between processes and threads as far as the scheduler is concerned.